# matching words based on user input

Tags: javascript

I have a fiddle setup to some code. There is an input filed where a user types into it. As the user types the input value should check for keywords. So if any character matches any of the keywords in each item it should return that item.

So if you type say "memb" it will return the correct item in the result array. Also if you complete the word "member" it works as you type a character. But when you move on to another word after the first word, like "time" it wont return the item until you complete all the characters of that word. How can I get it to return when any of the characters match on any of the term words.

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.list = [
     {
       keywords:['member', 'support', 'life'],
        content: 'This is my life',
      },
      {
       keywords:['time', 'working', 'life'],
        content: 'Cant stop working',
      },
      {
       keywords:['ball'],
        content: 'Help me play ball',
      },
    ];
  }
  
  onHandleChange = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const result = this.onSearch( value.toLowerCase());
    console.log('result = ', result);
  }
  
  onSearch = (term) => {
   if (term.length < 3) return '';
   return this.list.filter((item) => {
      return item.keywords.some(r => r.toLowerCase().includes(term) ||  term.includes(r.toLowerCase()));
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
     <input onChange={this.onHandleChange}/>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.done {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have worked with filter libraries in the past you will usually find that they all support a [tokenizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis#Tokenization)

In the example below I have used a very basic `String.prototype.split(" ")` tokenizer to split out each individual token/term.

```js
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.list = [
     {
       keywords:['member', 'support', 'life'],
        content: 'This is my life',
      },
      {
       keywords:['time', 'working', 'life'],
        content: 'Cant stop working',
      },
      {
       keywords:['ball'],
        content: 'Help me play ball',
      },
    ];
  }
  
  onHandleChange = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const result = this.onSearch( value.toLowerCase());
    console.log('result = ', result);
  }
  
  onSearch = (term) => {
   if (term.length < 3) return '';
   return this.list.filter((item) => {
      return item.keywords.some(r => term.split(" ").some(t =>
        r.toLowerCase().includes(t) ||  t.includes(r.toLowerCase())
      ));
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
     <input onChange={this.onHandleChange}/>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

input {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 400px;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.done {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```